# Change .page URL based on environment I need to run the suite in

Tags: javascript, testing, environment-variables, command-line-interface, testcafe

We have been building our automation suite using our staging environment, but are going live soon and want to be ready to tell the project where to run (staging, production).

The only difference between the sites in the environments is the URL. My question is, from start to finish, how can I set the .page URL via a CLI option?

Right now, I have created an environment config file that holds our staging and production URLS and then I call the data into my test files. This is fine for now, but I will need to create a script with an option to set the environment at runtime without having to do a manual find and replace before kicking it off.

I've looked around online and find, what I believe, to be code snippets and general instructions, but I'm not a dev at heart and go crossed eyed. If I could get an ELI5 for this, that would be awesome.

Example of what I'm doing now:

```
const env = require('../environment_variables.json')


fixture `blog`
  .page `${env.production}`
```

And then I change production to staging or vice versa manually before kicking off the suite.

Since the project will run from CICD, I would like to be able to do something like this in my CLI and script:

```
testcafe env=production
```

The env value will then be set where the .page call is for every test file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this. I've used environment variables successfully in this situation, so I'll share this solution since it will solve your problem.

I create `config.json` in the root of the project:

```json
{    
    "baseUrl": {
        "dev": "https://dev.com/",
        "staging": "https://staging.com/",
        "prod": "https://prod.com/"
    }
}
```

Then I create two helper functions somewhere like `Helpers/env.js`:

```js
import config from '../config';

function getEnv () {
    return process.env.TESTCAFE_ENV;
}

function getBaseUrl () {
    return config.baseUrl[getEnv()];
}

export { getEnv, getBaseUrl };
```

Then in my test files in `Tests/`:

```js
import { getBaseUrl } from '../Helpers/env';

const baseUrl = getBaseUrl();

fixture `Test Suite`
    .page(baseUrl);
```

And that's it. Then when I need to run tests on the dev, I execute:

```
$ TESTCAFE_ENV=dev testcafe
```

for staging:

```
$ TESTCAFE_ENV=staging testcafe
```

and for production:

```
$ TESTCAFE_ENV=prod testcafe
```

Comment: This works during my preliminary setup. I'm going to clean it up and push a PR. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

[In v1.20.0](https://testcafe.io/404002/release-notes/framework/2022-7-18-testcafe-v1-20-0-released#global-starting-url) and later, TestCafe offers a way to specify the `baseUrl` in the [test run configuration](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#baseurl). You can use this approach along with environment variables, see the following example:

*.testcaferc.js*

```js
const BASE_URL_MAP = {
    dev: 'https://dev.com/',
    staging: 'https://staging.com/',
    prod: 'https://prod.com/'
};

module.exports = {
    baseUrl: BASE_URL_MAP[process.env.TESTCAFE_ENV]
};
```

Alternatively, you can use different configuration files for each of the required setups using the [`--config-file` option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--config-file-path).